# Difference between Microsoft Unified Communication Products

Tags: sql-server, communication

What's the difference between the difference some of the Microsoft Unified Communication Products? Primarily Microsoft Office Live Meeting and Microsoft Office Communicator? The two seem very similar, but I don't quite know what each one is especially useful for.

Or are they all integrated into one product, but marketed as different products?

Comment: Does this belong on SuperUser?

Comment: Depends on the OP's intent. UC has an API for SIP Trunking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office Communicator is a Instant Messaging client, similar to Live Messenger, AIM, or Yahoo! Messenger.

Live Meeting is an application that allows you to conduct presentations.  You essentially have a room which people can join, see your desktop, or see powerpoint presentations.

Both of these products require a server install called Office Communications Server. The latest release is called OCS 2007 R2.